# unzip() is overwritting file, even when using overwrite = FALSE

Tags: r

```
saveRDS(1, tmp1 <- "test1.rds")
tmp3 <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
zip(tmp3, tmp1)
unlink(tmp1)
file.exists(tmp1)  # FALSE

unzip(tmp3)
file.exists(tmp1)  # TRUE
readRDS(tmp1)  # 1
saveRDS(2, tmp1)
readRDS(tmp1)  # 2
unzip(tmp3, overwrite = FALSE)
# Warning message:
#   In unzip(tmp3, overwrite = FALSE) :  not overwriting file './test1.rds
readRDS(tmp1)  # 1

unlink(tmp1)
```

I was expecting the last `readRDS(tmp1)` to return `2`, right?

Any thought?

PS: I'm on Linux CentOS 7, using R version 3.5.2.

Comment: This is working as expected for me on windows 10 environment with R 3.6.1. I got 2 at the end, not 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have confirmed that you are indeed facing a bug in `R 3.5.2`. I have checked on `Centos 7.2` only

**R 3.6.0**

```sh
$ /usr/bin/R -f test2.r

R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26) -- "Planting of a Tree"
Copyright (C) 2019 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

[Previously saved workspace restored]

During startup - Warning message:
Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C"
> saveRDS(1, tmp1 <- "test1.rds")
> tmp3 <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
> zip(tmp3, tmp1)
  adding: test1.rds (deflated 2%)
> unlink(tmp1)
> file.exists(tmp1)  # FALSE
[1] FALSE
>
> unzip(tmp3)
> file.exists(tmp1)  # TRUE
[1] TRUE
> readRDS(tmp1)  # 1
[1] 1
> saveRDS(2, tmp1)
> readRDS(tmp1)  # 2
[1] 2
> unzip(tmp3, overwrite = FALSE)
Warning message:
In unzip(tmp3, overwrite = FALSE) :  not overwriting file './test1.rds
> readRDS(tmp1)  # 1
[1] 2
>
> unlink(tmp1)
>
```

**R 3.5.2**

```sh
$ R -f test2.r

R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20) -- "Eggshell Igloo"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

[Previously saved workspace restored]

During startup - Warning message:
Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C"
> saveRDS(1, tmp1 <- "test1.rds")
> tmp3 <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
> zip(tmp3, tmp1)
  adding: test1.rds (deflated 5%)
> unlink(tmp1)
> file.exists(tmp1)  # FALSE
[1] FALSE
>
> unzip(tmp3)
> file.exists(tmp1)  # TRUE
[1] TRUE
> readRDS(tmp1)  # 1
[1] 1
> saveRDS(2, tmp1)
> readRDS(tmp1)  # 2
[1] 2
> unzip(tmp3, overwrite = FALSE)
Warning message:
In unzip(tmp3, overwrite = FALSE) :  not overwriting file './test1.rds
> readRDS(tmp1)  # 1
[1] 1
>
> unlink(tmp1)
>
```